# Eclipse Plugin for reading Java code of current project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to make an eclipse plugin which can analyze java code in the current project and display it in the editor.

`Scenario:`

On right-clicking the java file inside eclipse, I want my plugin option to be seen (which is successfully done) and on clicking it, an editor should open with the contents of that particular java file.

I am stuck at opening the java file and reading its contents. 
I think the `org.eclipse.jface.text` can be of help. 
For editor support, I am using `org.eclipse.ui.editors`.

How to proceed with reading the contents of particular java file that has been right clicked ?

I am new to eclipse plugin development. 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to open the existing Java editor or are you trying to write your own editor?

Comment: hello greg-449 : I don't want to build my own editor. 
I just want the contents of the java file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem even better way than expected.

In the handler class's execute method , I used `IWorkspace` and `IWorkspaceRoot` from org.eclipse.core.resources package.

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
```

From above code, I had access to each and every resource of the current workspace. I fetched the project using `IJavaProject` and filtered java files from the resources.